# Network state changed delay

Tags: android

Trying to monitor the offline state of the app by using a broadcast receiver on `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` but I’m experiencing a huge delay in the connection change when switching on and off the airplane mode, 20 - 30 seconds, is there any faster way? (without polling the connection)

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".service.NetworkStateReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Receiver:

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "\t\t\tCONNECTIVITY CHANGED");
    }
}
```

EDIT: there is a `D/NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect: Network connectivity changed, type is: 5` log in the logcat that is almost instant, is there a way to capture something that triggers that log?

EDIT: found that `android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE` is actually way quicker for reconnection. Dropping connection change still 20 to 30s delay :(

Comment: Which platform are you using for test? If you are using emulator, this can be natural because it is pretty slower than actual devices

Comment: @Kilanny on a real device, a Nexus 6P